# flask-Admin lazy pagination

Tags: python, flask, pagination, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-admin

Using flask, I have rather big tables (~10 Mio. entries) each corresponding to a flask-sqlAlchemy Model, which I want to build paginated Views for in flask-Admin.

I didn't find a way how to do lazy pagination in flask-Admin (i.e. loading the rows from database only for the current page the user is looking at, and fetching additional rows only when user changes the page). (Simply using `page_size` of my subclass of the `ModelView` still does an eager load.)

Does flask-Admin have a function for lazy pagination? If not, is there a known workaround? How can I implement this easily?

I know, I can write the view myself and use sqlAlchemy's `paginate`, but I would like to exploit the features of the flask-Admin Views (esp. `can_create`, `can_edit`, `can_delete`, `column_list`, `column_filters`, `column_searchable_list`, and so on) and I would like to avoid creating these functionalities on my own when they are already conveniently available in flask-Admin.

Comment: Flask-Admin already uses Limit and Offset when executing list view queries. Can you install [Flask-DebugToolbar](https://flask-debugtoolbar.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) - this will allow you to profile the queries being executed.

Comment: @pjcunningham Thanks for the hint. So I did so, and I cannot see any offset or limit in the SQL statements. Where can I find that flask-Admin uses it, as you mention?

Comment: Line 1026, [view.py](https://github.com/flask-admin/flask-admin/blob/master/flask_admin/contrib/sqla/view.py#L1036).